# cron that keeps a log of file names that it removes

Tags: logging, cron

I have a configured cron to invoke find periodically. The find program should delete files from directory if they have not been modified in the last 5 hours. I want store a list of the files that find has deleted. How can this be achieved? This is the line from my cronttab:

```
0,30 * * * * find /var/log/custom/messages -mmin +300 -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add -print to your cron job command line, cron prints the names of the files it deletes. If you put your commandline into a script you have more flexibility in controlling where the output goes.

Comment: another question, I can now see the deleted file names but log gets truncated the next time cron runs, how can I stop this from happening? I want log to keep records of all deleted file names. Thanks